# WPF: Adding a ProgressBar to ListBox Items

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemtemplate, z-order

I'm trying to make the background of my ListBoxItems to be constituted of a ProgressBar, but the "Z-Index" thing is not seemingly working for me. I have read somewhere that Grid doesn't support Z-Index (like Canvas) and that by default elements are rendered in the order they are added. This is what apparently happens in my case too. But when I click on a listbox item, my TextBlock (see below) disappears, apparently because the ProgressBar comes to front. Interestingly, the other child controls (image and animation) do not disappear, so I'm kind of puzzled.

Here's my ListBox's ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Name="ListBoxGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ProgressBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="White" Value="{Binding Path=SendProgress}" />
            <Image Width="50" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Image}" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=ImageFilePath, Padding="20,0,0,0" />
            <Canvas Grid.Column="2">
                <Image Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="25" Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Status}" />
                <my:LoadingAnimation HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Visibility="{Binding IsSending, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter1}}" />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Grid supports Panel.ZIndex property for its children

Comment: That's correct. What I later found was that when I selected an item in the ListBox, the TextBlock's text color would turn White (as it normally happens when we select text in TextBoxes and Lists in both WinForms and WPF) and therefore disappeared into the White ProgressBar. It was not a Z-Index problem as such. However, this single post helped me learn two good things about WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panel.ZIndex property works fine for me Sample code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="2">
        <Button Name="goButton" Height="30" Width="50" Margin="0,10,0,50" Click="goButton_Click">GO!</Button>
        <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Width="300" Height="30" />
    </StackPanel>

        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="100" Content="SHOWTHIS" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Perhaps Style Datatriggers for visibility might be usefull in this case if i understood it well
Sample code for each element of your datatemplate:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSending}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSending}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Plz note that I do not need to hide/show my controls dynamically. All I want is that the ProgressBar and other controls keep their Z-order the same as they were designed. 

Apart from this, what you have done can be achieved simply by directly Binding Visibility to IsSending property (with a converter). No? Or is there a difference?

Comment: Panel.ZIndex worked fine in my sample code that i added before. As for the visibility ok you can do it with converterclasses but it can also be done just in xaml like this. benefit: No need to write a converter class.

Comment: Sorry I missed your edit. Panel.ZIndex actually is the correct answer. My previous comment was about the DataTrigger tip.